# Send raw printer codes after writing a FlowDocument, but before automatically cutting

Tags: printing, xps

**The Good**:  I'm building a FlowDocument in my app and sending it to a Star Micronics TSP100 thermal receipt printer, and I can print bar codes as well by sending ESC codes to the printer directly.

**The Bad**:  It's automatically cutting the paper after the FlowDocument, before the bar codes have had a chance to print.

**The Question**:  Is there a better way to print the FlowDocument so it doesn't tell the printer it's done printing?  Or to have the some part of that trigger an event handler so I can squeeze my bar code commands in before it tells the printer it's done?

**Here's where I am now**:

The flow document is called, creatively enough, "doc".

```
FlowDocument doc
```

Then of course, I add a whole bunch of stuff to the FlowDocument.  Then I grab the printer and print the FlowDocument:

```
string printerName = "Star TSP100 Cutter (TSP143)";
LocalPrintServer local = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue rcptpq = local.GetPrintQueue(printerName);
Xps.XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(rcptpq);
IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = doc;
```

If that all worked without errors (error handling not copied--this is what I'm stepping through), I write out the receipt:

```
// print MOST of the receipt
xpsdw.Write(dps.DocumentPaginator);
```

The printer cuts here automatically.  I don't want it to.  I want it to cut *after* the bar code.

```
// print the bar code
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName,"\x1b\x62\x2\x2\x30" + "MyUPC123\n"); 

// Cut the paper
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName,"\x1b\x64\x02");
```

*(RawPrinterHelper is from the Star Micronics SDK sample, and what it does is pretty self explanatory, at least with my comments to describe the specific codes being used.)*

I've tried some settings in TSP100's Configuration tool regarding "Page end detection", but so far all I've succeeded in doing is turning off all cutting, or turning off the explicit "cut the paper" command at the end.  I can't just turn off the first cut.

Comment: Looks like you need to disable both the page and document cuts in the printer properties, then issue the cut manually.

Comment: If I disable everything, the manual cut is disabled, too.  If I enable the manual cut, it enables the document/page cut, too.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the printer is done processing the FlowDocument print job before sending the raw escape codes.  This could possibly be done by polling the [PrintQueue.IsPrinting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isprinting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or by checking [PrintQueue.QueueStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.queuestatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But... but... I *am* waiting for the FlowDocument to finish.  My problem is hitting the spot after the content is rendered, but before the FlowDocument printing issues the paper cut.  :-/

Comment: When the FlowDocument is finished, the job may not be printed. The print job is spooled, sent to the printer, and processed by the printer.  If the document is in the print spooler when you send the escape codes, it will cut too early.

Comment: I've run it in the debugger--the FlowDocument had been printed for several seconds and cut before I stepped into the code that sends the raw codes.

Comment: If the printer is cutting before you send the raw codes to perform the cut, the printer driver must be sending a cut command to the printer.  Is there a way to disable cutting in the Star Micronics printer driver?

Comment: Not in code that I've seen.  I know there *is*, because there's a configuration tool that lets you set that in a GUI, but it's not documented in their API anywhere.  I could switch over to another similar brand (Epson?) if I knew I had a solution that would work; we're only using Star Micronics for historical reasons that are now moot.  (Make a company $10k/location/yr, and they'll switch receipt printers if you say it'll get them what they want! :-D )